# codeigniter: htaccess filtering out css?

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website which has a broken link structure. The initial page loads normally. My Navbar looks like:

```
<a class="brand" href="#">myproject</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/Facts">Facts</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/about">About</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact">Contact</a></li>
              <!--<li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/privacy">Privacy</a></li>-->
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I know this project worked correctly in the past . I believe it was deployed with a .htaccess file which is not present locally as I test it.

I've tested it with  the following .htaccess file in the toot directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This appears to fix the directory structure by turning:

```
http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact
```

into:

```
http://localhost/projectname/index.php/basecontroller/contact
```

but now all the js/css does not appear to be applied to the page ( I'm using bootstrap ).

The head of my pages looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
        <base href="http://localhost/projectname/">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my title </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">    

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine that adding the `css` and `js` folders to the `RewriteCond` should do the trick (or whatever you named those directories):

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
```

This excludes those paths from the rewrite rule posted below.

Comment: Thanks, That worked. Also I didn't realize that you can put folders in the RewriteCond

Answer (score 1):

As sbeliv01 said, you'll probably want to add css and js folders to the RewriteCond, to exclude them from rewrites.

I also notice from the head section...

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

... you're loading CSS from a relative URL, so `http://localhost/projectname/` will load CSS from `http://localhost/projectname/css/bootstrap-responsive.css`, while `http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/facts/` will load from `http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/facts/css/bootstrap-responsive.css`.  You probably want to change your head section as follows:

```
<link href="http://localhost/projectname/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually setting the base tag like in http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/09/Asset-handling-in-CodeIgniter-with-the-BASE-tag. It makes deployment easier.

Comment: That's the best way for sure.